# Creating multiple log level for same package in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging

In my case, I have to create each log level in a separate file. Log level will create for the same package. For example, my package name is com.example. I need to mention log level info and debug for this package.

Use case:

```
      Scheduler related function log will be in debug and client request related function log will be in info.
```

Comment: Please make sure you follow the suggestions in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to ask good questions. I'm not really sure how to help you with the level of detail provided in your question.

Answer (score 0):

1- Add log4j dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>docx4j</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.5</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

2- in this step you should create a `log4j.properties` file in your project root:

mine was this : projectDirectory -> src -> main -> resources -> log4j.properties

and config your log4j file like this:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, consul
log4j.logger.producer=INFO, producer
log4j.logger.consumer=INFO, consumer
log4j.logger.connection=INFO, connection


log4j.appender.consul=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.consul.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Stdout.threshold=info
log4j.appender.consul.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{[yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss]} [%r ms]     %C %-5p - %m%n

# LOG4J daily rolling log for producer
log4j.appender.producer=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.producer.File=log/producerLog/producer.log
log4j.appender.producer.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.producer.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.producer.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{[yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss]} [%r     ms] %C %-5p - %m%n

# LOG4J daily rolling log for consumer
log4j.appender.consumer=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.consumer.File=log/consumerLog/consumer.log
log4j.appender.consumer.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.consumer.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.consumer.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{[yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss]} [%r ms] %C %-5p - %m%n

# LOG4J daily rolling log for connection
log4j.appender.connection=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.connection.File=log/connectionLog/connection.log
log4j.appender.connection.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.connection.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.connection.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{[yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss]} [%r ms] %C %-5p - %m%n
```

this config will provide the logs of each action separately, everyday that you could manually define. it will create the log files in your project root. the ConversionPattern could be personalized...